# Is the free space of unmounted partitions and hard disks used in the background when the OS needs some more space?

Tags: mount, hard-disk

I have two hard disks on a computer  and I intend to recover the data in one of the them (Hard Disk 1). An Ubuntu OS is installed on the other (Hard Disk 2).

Both Hard Disks are connected to the computer and I boot into the Ubuntu OS in Hard Disk 2. Does Ubuntu use the space in Hard Disk 1 if its partitions are not mounted?

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. Beware that even if your drive lets say `/dev/sdb`, you run `mount` and see that there is no `/dev/sdb`, it's still possible that partitions of the drive are mounted by label or by uuid. In such case, use `blkid` to find out which label/uuid belongs to which drive. Some applications (like virtual machines) may use partitions directly use `fuser /dev/sdb1` to find out such cases.

If no partitions are mounted, you under some conditions (your SATA controller supports it) can even hot remove/install SATA disks like ordinary removable device as USB flash. OS doesn't use anything on it.